# Cassandra LongType column name to String issue

Tags: java, cassandra, thrift

I am using java and cassandra thrift to fetch a rowkey from the Column Family having Comparator as LongType.

Here is the code I am using:

```
for (ColumnOrSuperColumn column : slice) {
    Column col = column.getColumn();
    System.out.println("Column Name: " + new String(col.name.array()));
    System.out.println("Column Name: " + new String(col.name.array(), "UTF-8"));
    System.out.println("Column Name: " + new String(col.getName(), "UTF-8" ) );
}
```

*slice* is a list of *ColumnOrSuperColumn* object which holds the data retrieved from the ColumnFamily.

The problem is none of the print statement prints the long column names as String. I want those long values as string to create a json statement. What I am dong wrong here?? Is there any other ways to get the expected output?

Cassandra Version: 1.1.0

Answer (score 2):

Since the comparator is LongType, the content of col.name.array() is a long (8 bytes), not a string.

So you need a method to convert 8 bytes to long. Since thrift uses ByteBuffer underneath, the simplest way to do that would be to use:

```
System.out.println("Column name: " + col.name.getLong(0));
```

But note that this is typically the sort of reason why it is generally advised to not use the thrift API directly, but rather to use a higher level client that will deserialize the type correctly for you.